# What is wrong with my object

Tags: javascript, object

So I have a (bugged) javascript object:

```
var computer={
 "Home":{
    "Applications":{
        "Desktop":{

        }
        "Documents":{

        }
        "Downloads":{

        }
        "Library":{

        }
        "Movies":{

        }
        "Music":{

        }
        "Pictures":{

        }
    }
}
"Library":{

}
"Downloads":{

}
"Files":{
    personnel
}
"Devices":{
    "USB":{

    }
    "HardDrive":{

    }

}
}
```

i know javascript object can contain more objects, but safari console and jslint are throwing an error. And I can't seem to find the error. What's wrong?

Comment: Comma, comma, comma, comma, comma, chameleon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do miss commas `,`

```
var computer={
 "Home":{
    "Applications":{
        "Desktop":{

        },
        "Documents":{

        },
        "Downloads":{

        },
        "Library":{

        },
        "Movies":{

        },
        "Music":{

        },
        "Pictures":{

        }
    }
},
"Library":{

},
"Downloads":{

},
"Files":{
    personnel: ''
},
"Devices":{
    "USB":{

    },
    "HardDrive":{

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the commas between the brackets...

Should look like this:

```
var computer={
 "Home":{
    "Applications":{
        "Desktop":{

        },
        "Documents":{

        },
        "Downloads":{

        },
        "Library":{

        },
        "Movies":{

        },
        "Music":{

        },
        "Pictures":{

        }
    }
},
"Library":{

},
"Downloads":{

},
"Files":{
    personnel: ''
},
"Devices":{
    "USB":{

    },
    "HardDrive":{

        }    
}
}
```